# Blank Page PHP - HTML - CSS

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin

I made a login page taking help from online sources. Its not really a login page its a nick-status Verification page. It takes data from database and if the value/nick exists it redirects to a page now that's where I'm having problem.

I think it's connected to database successfully as it only starts redirection when i enter the correct nick otherwise gives the error that i have told it too. But aftet entering correct name it redirects to a blank page.

This is is the link where im testing it : [pakwar.byethost3.com/login/login.php](http://pakwar.byethost3.com/login/login.php)

And the correct value is : udamnkilledme

Here Are My Files As I couldnt use CLTR K Or Code toolbar button in android:- Solved
Database sequence :-
Database -> Table:- admin -> coloumn-> usr

Comment: Have you tried the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851

Comment: Not really , well after enabling error this is what i got:al error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function session_register() in /home/vol5_8/byethost3.com/b3_20155311/htdocs/login/login.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/vol5_8/byethost3.com/b3_20155311/htdocs/login/login.php on line 20

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: you should delete the question and there's no code to support the question, just an answer using a deprecated function

Comment: -_- Man There was code but i deleted it cause i got my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well i seem to have solved it for now after enabling errors i got this :- session_register() so i changed it